# How to bind image to UIImageView with rxswift?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uiimageview, rx-swift

I have viewModel:

```
class EditFoodViewViewModel {
    private var food: Food

    var foodImage = Variable<NSData>(NSData())

    init(food: Food) {
        self.food = food
        self.foodImage.value = food.image!
    }
}
```

And ViewController:

```
class EditFoodViewController: UIViewController {
    public var food: EditFoodViewViewModelType?
    @IBOutlet weak var foodThumbnailImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let foodViewModel = food else { return }
        foodViewModel.foodImage.asObservable().bind(to: foodThumbnailImageView.rx.image).disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

In the last line of viewController (where my UIImageView) a get error:

> Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred

How to solve my problem? How to set image to imageView with rxSwift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost invariably, when you see the error: "Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred", it means that the types are wrong. In this case you are trying to bind an `Observable<NSData>` to an `Observable<Image?>`.

There's a few other issues with your code as well.

- it is very rare that a Subject type should be defined with the `var` keyword and this is not one of those rare times. Your `foodImage` should be a `let` not a `var`.
- `Variable` has been deprecated; don't use it. In this case, you don't even need a subject at all.
- `NSData` is also inappropriate in modern Swift. Use `Data` instead.

Based on what you have shown here, I would expect your code to look more like this:

```
class EditFoodViewViewModel: EditFoodViewViewModelType {
    let foodImage: Observable<UIImage?>

    init(food: Food) {
        self.foodImage = Observable.just(UIImage(data: food.image))
    }
}

class EditFoodViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodThumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    public var food: EditFoodViewViewModelType?
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let foodViewModel = food else { return }
        foodViewModel.foodImage
            .bind(to: foodThumbnailImageView.rx.image)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```